# links in kml balloons not working in GE 6

Tags: kml, google-earth

My KML placemarks have the description element populated as such

```
<description>
<![CDATA[
some text
<a href="urlReturningKML">someTag</a>
]]>
</description>
```

With Google Earth 5, when you click on the link in the balloon, the kml is downloaded and displayed as expected.

With Google Earth pro 6, when you click on the link in the balloon, nothing happens.  You have to right click on the link and then select "Open in New Window".  Then the KML is downloaded and displayed in Google Earth.

Does anyone know why there is the behavoir difference between GE 5 and GE6?  How do I get links in kml balloons to download in GE6 without requiring the right click workaround

Comment: Are you using a relative URL to a file at same location/context as the first KML, or inside a KMZ file, or absolute URL (e.g. http://...) ??

Answer (score 0):

There were some updates to handling URLs and hrefs between GE 5 and 6. GE 5 allowed some sloppy URLs and 6.0 became stricter in a few places to better conform to the specs. There weren't a lot of details on the specifics. Check the syntax of the URL and make sure it opens in your web browser.

Note if you want to fly-to a target Placemark in another KML file you specify the id of that Placemark as an anchor in the URL with a "#" followed by the id (see example below in second link).

Here's a KML example that works in GE 6.2.2:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Placemark>
      <name>Test</name>
      <description>
        <![CDATA[ 
    <a href="http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kml/startingPlaces.kml">test URL#1</a>
    <P>
    <a href="http://kml4earth.appspot.com/kml/startingPlaces.kml#MtWashington">test URL#2 w/anchor</a>
        ]]>
      </description>
      <Point>
        <coordinates>-123.0821604290386,37.42041505714916</coordinates>
      </Point>
    </Placemark>
</kml>
```